How can carbonic acid exist?
I've recently been studying the tests for ions, including the test for carbonate ions - simply adding a dilute acid and then bubbling the gas given off through limewater to confirm it as carbon dioxide.
The reaction that forms the carbon dioxide is between the carbonate ions in the analysed substance and the hydrogen ions in the acid (also producing water).
My textbook says that any acid would be suitable for this test, and this makes sense, as carbon dioxide will be produced regardless of the other aqueous anion in the acid.
One acid that I'm familiar with is carbonic acid ($\ce{H2CO3}$) which I believe disassociates into the ions $\ce{2H+}$ and $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ in an aqueous state.
But as previously stated, in the test for carbonate ions, carbonate ions and hydrogen ions react to form carbon dioxide and water, with the relevant ionic equation is as follows:
$\ce{2H+ + CO3^{2-} -> CO2 + H2O}$
So how can carbonic acid exist in a state of separated aqueous ions without the ions reacting as above?

Well, do you know what equilibrium is?

And if you are interested: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124487/does-h3co3-ion-exist-and-what-is-its-structure

$$\ce{CO2(g) <=>[H2O]CO2(aq) <=>[+H2O]H2CO3(aq)\
<=>[-H+]HCO3^- <=>[- H+]CO3^2-}$$

Thank you @NilayGhosh for finding a similar question with answers (that mention equilibrium, just like Mithoron hinted at)

Only as a minor species in aqueous solutions as they normally exist, but it's there according to the equilibrium
$\ce{CO2 + H2O <=> O=C(OH)2}$
Chemists have found that ultrapure, perfectly dry carbonic acid is a (meta)stable gas at room temperature,[1].
Aqueous formaldehyde, whose carbonyl group is more strongly electrophilic and less sterically encumbered than its counterparts in other aldehydes and ketones, undergoes a similar equilibrium, but more favored for the hydroxylated form:
$\ce{H2CO + H2O <=> H2C(OH)2}$
Reference

Loerting, Thomas; Tautermann, Christofer; Kroemer, Romano T.; Kohl, Ingrid; Hallbrucker, Andreas; Mayer, Erwin; Liedl, Klaus R.; Loerting, Thomas; Tautermann, Christofer; Kohl, Ingrid; Hallbrucker, Andreas; Erwin, Mayer; Liedl, Klaus R. (2000).  "On the Surprising Kinetic Stability of Carbonic Acid (H2CO3)". Angewandte Chemie International Edition. 39 (5): 891–4. doi:10.1002/(SICI)1521-3773(20000303)39:5<891::AID-ANIE891>3.0.CO;2-E. PMID 10760883

